# Qt provided dll sizes

Tags: qt

I've noted Qt provided DLLs with the same name but different sizes in different locations, for example:

246 KB C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Qt5OpenGL.dll

vs

316 KB C:\Qt\Qt5.3.2\5.3\mingw482_32\bin\Qt5OpenGL.dll

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools directory is compiled with some "default" compiler for the target platform and all the files from there intended to serve build tools and Qt Creator, QML Debugger and other tools. Qt Company has selected one of available compilers for that.

And for specific platform/compiler Qt precompiled build you've installed the other compiler is used which is producing binaries of different size from that same code.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your Qt installation contains Qt Creator and Qt libs with compiler (mingw).

Your Qt Creator was compiled with the Microsoft compiler (msvc) (you can see About window), so in your Qt Creator dir you have dlls compiled by msvc. But to be honest, it doesn't mean that you can't compile Qt Creator with mingw, you can do this, but currently I think that you don't need this.

So far so good, but there is also Qt libs and mingw. Mingw and msvc are not compatible, so you if you want to use mingw, you need dlls which was compiled by mingw (g++), not a msvc. And these dlls locates in your mingw dir.

In conclusion, if you will create some exe with mingw, you should use dlls compiled by mingw too! In another case you will get weird errors like "entry point not found ..."